# optimize a simple class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to write the following class shorter?

```
<div class="col-sm-7 small-padding-right small-padding-top small-padding-bottom">
```

I am thinking fx something like:

```
small-padding-right top bottom
```

```css
.small-padding-top {
    padding-left:5px;
}

.small-padding-bottom {
    padding-right:5px;
} 
.small-padding-left {
    padding-left:5px;
}

.small-padding-right {
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 small-padding-right small-padding-top small-padding-bottom">
        <div class="content">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding-left">
                <div class="sidebar-top">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding-left">
                <div class="sidebar-bottom">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well you could use shorter class names

Comment: After the documentation I need to use those class names:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine class names when you declaring it.

```
.small-padding.top {
   padding-top:5px;
}

.small-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom:5px;
} 
.small-padding.left {
    padding-left:5px;
}

.small-padding.right {
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Then your HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-7 small-padding top right bottom">
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-sm-12 small-padding left">
  <div class="sidebar-top"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.small-padding.top {
   padding-top:5px;
}

.small-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom:5px;
} 
.small-padding.left {
    padding-left:5px;
}

.small-padding.right {
    padding-right:5px;
}
.red {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-7 small-padding top right bottom">
   <div class="red">No left padding</div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-12 small-padding left">
  <div class="red">Only left padding</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 small-padding top">
  <div class="red">Only top padding</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 small-padding bottom">
  <div class="red">Only bottom padding</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 small-padding right">
  <div class="red">Only right padding</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. It seems deffently the correct way to do it. I can see the space between the column are not equal, and the bottom sidebar is to short? https://www.bootply.com/rw52McNahg

Comment: Your class `.small-padding.bottom` contains `padding-right:5px;` instead  `padding-bottom:5px;`, please correct your classes values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```css
[class*="padT"] {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

[class*="padB"] {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

[class*="padL"] {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

[class*="padR"] {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 padR-padT-padB">
        <div class="content">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 padL">
                <div class="sidebar-top">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 padL">
                <div class="sidebar-bottom">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the class name that you suggest is possible. Just make a new css style for a particular tag

```
<div class="col-sm-7 small-padding-right small-padding-top small-padding-bottom">
```

You can make a new class and make a style based on this new class like this

```
<div class="col-sm-7 padding-header">
```

CSS

```
.small-padding-left {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px; /* only the left side doesn't have padding like your original html code.*/
}
```

By the way, aren't `.small-padding-top` css supposed to contain `padding-top` instead of `padding-left`? The same goes for `.small-padding-bottom`.